# Google Play Services for Froyo

Tags: android, google-play-services

I updated SDk for android after 4.4 release. I saw that they have bifurcated Google Play Services and Google Play Services for Froyo. What is the reason behind this? Now suppose I want to use integrate Google Map in app how to use these two services for the Google Map Integration ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Per the [Google Play Services 4.0 announcement](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/google-play-services-40.html):

> With over 97% of devices now running Android 2.3 (Gingerbread) or newer platform versions, we’re dropping support for Froyo from this release of the Google Play services SDK in order to make it possible to offer more powerful APIs in the future. That means you will not be able to utilize these new APIs on devices running Android 2.2 (Froyo).

If you use the 'Google Play Services for Froyo', you will not be able to use the new features included in Google Play Service 4.0. For Maps, the 4.0 features include

> The Maps API enhances map customization features, letting you specify marker opacity, fade-in effects, and visibility of 3D buildings. It’s also now possible to change ground overlay images.