# your device isn't compatible with version android 2.2

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-play-services, android-resources

My app on google playstore. I have updated some function in that and release updated version on playstore but after release its can not available on android 2.2 device.

here my Androidmanifest.xml code snippets of `uses-sdk` and `uses-permission`.

Androidmanifest.xml

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="com.cvonline.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
                android:protectionLevel="normal" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.cvonline.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

```
 <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need Google Play Services for Froyo which you can get from SDK Manager.

[image]

But by referring [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899798/google-play-services-for-froyo), and [announcement](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/google-play-services-40.html) from Google.

> If you use the 'Google Play Services for Froyo', you will not be able
>   to use the new features included in Google Play Service 4.0. For Maps,
>   the 4.0 features include
>
> The Maps API enhances map customization features, letting you specify
>   marker opacity, fade-in effects, and visibility of 3D buildings. It’s
>   also now possible to change ground overlay image

Comment: thank you for your answer but it was done by me. the problem is my app update is not available for android 2.2 after release it on playstore.