# Unable to find google play services for Froyo in SDK Manager in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an application in which i used google maps. It was tested on a samsung galaxy ace phone, and i used the google play services for froyo package to enable me work with the map.

I now want to replicate the project on Android Studio,but the issue is that the SDK manager has no entry for

```
 'google play services for froyo'
```

to aid me download the package.

How do i get the

```
    'google play services for froyo' package?.
```

I am using Android Studio version

```
   1.2.1.1
```

Comment: you can simply use google play services for the same

Comment: I thought google play services DOES NOT support froyo?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899798/google-play-services-for-froyo Google ended GPS support for Froyo almost 2 years ago. They may have removed Froyo-compatible version of GPS from the SDK Manager.

Comment: is there no way i can download the package...and add it manually to the project without using SDK manager?

Comment: Google may be  removed all support from froyo , you can visit google dash board https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking hide obsolete package checkbox, then you will see it. Click the google play services for froyo checkbox and then click ok (or Apply if you want to stay) to install it.

Comment: :) i completed sign up!